# How to flatten json properties to _source used ELK?

Tags: json, indexing, elastic-stack, flatten

Suppose I have these 2 log messages send to logstash/elasticsearch:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "Message": "Get all motors",
            "Level": "Information"
        },
        {
            "Message": "Get all motors",
            "Level": "Information"
        }
    ]
}
```

The expected search result:

```
"hits" : {
  "total" : 2,
  "max_score" : 1.0,
  "hits" : [
    {
      "_source" : {
        "@timestamp" : "2019-03-28T10:05:05.649Z",
        "@version" : "1",
        "Message" : "Get all motors",
        "Level" : "Information"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source" : {
        "@timestamp" : "2019-03-28T10:05:05.649Z",
        "@version" : "1",
        "Message" : "Get all motors",
        "Level" : "Information"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I used below logstash config:

```
# Http input listening port 8080
input {
    http {  
        #default host 0.0.0.0:8080
        codec => json
    }
}

# Separate the logs
filter {
    split {
        field => "events"
        target => "e"
    }

    mutate {        
        remove_field => ["events", "headers"]
    }
}

# Send the logs to Elasticsearch
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index=>"mylog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "log"
    }
}
```

The actual search result:

```
"hits" : {
  "total" : 2,
  "max_score" : 1.0,
  "hits" : [
    {
      "_source" : {
        "@timestamp" : "2019-03-28T10:05:05.649Z",
        "@version" : "1",
        "e" : {
          "Message" : "Get all motors",
          "Level" : "Information"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_source" : {
        "@timestamp" : "2019-03-28T10:05:05.649Z",
        "@version" : "1",
        "e" : {
          "Message" : "Get all motors",
          "Level" : "Information"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The different is:

- In the actual result, my log info is nested in `e` property
- I want all the log info props flattened (direct children of `_source`)

Elasticsearch document suggest remove `target` from `filter`:

```
filter {
    split {
        field => "events"
    }
}
```

But if I do that, my result will be empty:

```
"hits" : {
  "total" : 2,
  "max_score" : 1.0,
  "hits" : [
    {
      "_source" : {
        "@timestamp" : "2019-03-28T10:05:05.649Z",
        "@version" : "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source" : {
        "@timestamp" : "2019-03-28T10:05:05.649Z",
        "@version" : "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve the expected result?

My environment:

- Windows 10 x64 Pro
- ELK 6.7
- JDK 8u201

Answer (score 0):

remove the `target => "e"` part, your target is the root of the document.

Comment: I tried that. If I remove it, the log info will not be recorded at all

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough, don't remove the line, but make it target the root of the document, not "e"